# Write each var input on a new line in a text file

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can make this irc 'bot' log to a text file.

I used:

```
  text_file = open("log.txt", "w")
  text_file.write(ircmsg +"\r\n")
  text_file.close()
```

The problem is that this code will make new input overwrite the textfile, while I want every new input a new line in the same text file.

(I know there are 'made bots' on the internet, but I prefer making it myself.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you append to file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are opening file in 'write' mode which would override file each time
Open in 'append' mode i.e use `'a'` instead of `'w'`
More details here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files